# How to change each word color in react content

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a task where I need to change the color of each word in a sentence or paragraph in react code for every 1 second.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      colors: ["red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "purple", "pink"]
    };

    this.changeBg = this.changeBg.bind(this);
  }

componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.changeBg, 1000);
 }

  changeBg() {
    const { colors } = this.state;
    const color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        This is a sample message in react template
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This works fine in changing the background of the content. But my task is to change each word color randomly for every 1 second.

Example for text **This is a sample message in react template**

`This` should have one color, `is` should have another color, similarly all words. How can I do this?

Now these colors should change again every 1 second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the sentence on word breaks (spaces) and then apply the randomly chosen color as a style for each word.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      colors: ["red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "purple", "pink"],
      sampleMessage: "This is a sample message in react template",
      refresh: 0
    };
  }

  refresh() {
    let { refresh } = this.state;
    refresh = refresh + 1;
    this.setState({ refresh });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.refresh.bind(this), 1000);
  }

  render() {
    const { sampleMessage, colors, refreshRate } = this.state;

    const randomColor = () => {
      return colors[(Math.random() * colors.length) >> 0];
    };

    return (
      <div>
        {sampleMessage.split(" ").map(word => {
          return <span style={{ color: randomColor() }}>{`${word} `}</span>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

see it working here
https://codesandbox.io/s/random-word-colors-lu5ew

Comment: Thanks, but I want the color of words to change randomly every 1 second, how can I do that?

Comment: Can you please explain how the colors are changing? I can see that randomColor method generates a random color from the colors array, now how this value is going to change after 1 second, I am not clear on that part. `this.refresh.bind(this)` is being called for every second, but how this is changing the color of words?

Comment: I added a refresh 'counter' in the state which is updated every second by the setInterval kicked off when component mounts. (whenever a component's state changes, the component will re-render). so each time a re-render happens randomColor() is called again for each word. this.refresh.bind(this) is running the refresh function within the scope of setInterval. Ideally this type of approach would only be done inside a smaller component, not on a root level component/app, but this code is just for an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom component for reuse and replace the html elements to your style needs.

Use case:

```
<ColorPara>Hello world</ColorPara>
```

Here's an example:

```
const getRandomColor = () => {
  const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue']
  return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}

const ColorPara = (props) => {

  return (
    <p>
      {props.children.split(' ').map(text => {
        return (
          <p style={{ color: getRandomColor(), display: 'inline', }}>
            {text} &nbsp;
          </p>
        )
      })}
    </p>
  )
}

function App() {
  //For changing on interval
  //-------------------------
  const [count, setCount ] = useState(0)

  setInterval(() => {
    let newCount = count + 1
    setCount(newCount)
  }, 2000);
  //--------------------------


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ColorPara>This is something</ColorPara>
    </div >
  );
}
```

[image]
[image]

edit: added image, added description above block of code, added gif, added color change on interval

Comment: How to change this color for every 1 second?

Comment: @learner a simple way would be to re render the component, I've updated the code for this. In the code I'm using React Hooks

Answer (score 0):

For each word to have a separate color, it would need to be contained in a discrete element that is able to be individually targeted by CSS.

```
<div>This is a message</div>
```

Can only have one CSS rule defining the text color,

```
<span>This</span><span>is</span><span>better</span>
```

can have one for each element.

I'd recommend storing your text in state, splitting it into words like any other string, and iterating over the resulting array to render separate elements that you can style as you see fit.

Not sure what you mean exactly by "change randomly," but I tried to make the most basic example I could [here](https://codepen.io/extrachrisb/pen/rNNqRpz)